# Python: ftp and progressbar 2.3

Tags: python, ftp, progress-bar

I have an ftp program using ftplib and for the past couple of days I have been trying to figure out how to implement a progress bar for retrbinary and storbinary. I am trying to use the progressbar 2.3 module but have had no luck in getting it to tie in. I think this may stem from a misunderstanding of how the callback function works. Anyway here is what I have.

```
import progressbar
import ftplib


ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("host", "port")
ftp.login("user", "pwd")


widgets = ['Downloading: ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar(marker=RotatingMarker()),
       ' ', ETA(), ' ', FileTransferSpeed()]
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=1024).start()

def callback(p):
    for i in range(1024):
        pbar.update(10*i+1)
        pbar.finish()

ftp.storbinary("STOR iTunesSetup.exe", open("iTunesSetup.exe"), callback, blocksize=1024)
```

I get this error although this is just one of many ways I have tried this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "progrbar.py", line 7, in <module>
    ftp.connect("host", "port")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 132, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -8] Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

I can say without this callback the  ftp server works just fine and has more then enough space to download. If someone can give me some pointers I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any future visitors this is how I did it...

```
def handleupload(self, block):
    self.pbar.update(self.pbar.currval+len(block))

def upload(self):
    try:
        if os.path.getsize(self.filename) == 0:
            print "%s 0 bytes passing..." % self.filename
        else:
            print "Uploading %s-%d-bytes" % (self.filename, self.ftp.size(self.filename))
            self.pbar=ProgressBar(widgets=[FileTransferSpeed(),' ', Bar(marker=RotatingMarker()), ' ', 
                                                    Percentage(),' ', ETA()],    maxval=os.path.getsize(self.filename)).start()
            self.ftp.storbinary("STOR " + self.filename, open(self.filename), 
                                                        callback = s.handleupload, blocksize = 1024)
            self.pbar.finish() 
            print "Finished"
    except (error_perm, error_temp, Exception), self.exc:
        print self.exc
```